# Eclipse linking with Access not working trying to update

Tags: java, eclipse, ms-access

Struggling to workout why the database linkup with access is bringing in errors. cannot seem to update the field in the database.

```
/**
* Displaying, inserting into, updating, deleting from a database table.
* This subclass provides a method to update a record with values specified  on
* the command line.  It inherits all the JDBC connection functionality from
* BorrowerDisplay class.
*
* The updated table is displayed. (Display method inherited from superclass)
*/

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Update extends MainDisplay {
    private PreparedStatement sqlUpdate = null;

    public boolean connect() {
        boolean ok = super.connect(); // superclass's connect () loads the JDBC
        try { // driver & connects to the DB engine.
            sqlUpdate = connection.prepareStatement(
                    "UPDATE Ticket SET TicketNo = ?,   TransactTime = ?, SaleID = ?, ScheduleID = ?, Price = ? "
                            + " WHERE TicketNo = ? AND TransactTime = ? AND SaleID = ? AND ScheduleID = ? AND Price = ?");
        } catch (SQLException sqlex) {
            System.err.println("SQL Exception");
            sqlex.printStackTrace();
            ok = false;
        }
        return ok;
    }

    public boolean updateTicket() throws SQLException {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("TicketNo to change: ");
        int TicketNo = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter current Transaction Time: ");
        int TransactTime = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter new Transaction Time: ");
        int newTransactTime = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter current SaleID: ");
        int SaleID = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter new SaleID: ");
        int newSaleID = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter current ScheduleID: ");
        String ScheduleID = scan.next();

        System.out.print("Enter new Schedule ID: ");
        String newScheduleID = scan.next();

        System.out.print("Enter current Price: ");
        int Price = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter new Price: ");
        int newPrice = scan.nextInt();

        sqlUpdate.setInt(1, TicketNo);

        sqlUpdate.setInt(2, newTransactTime);

        sqlUpdate.setInt(3, newSaleID);

        sqlUpdate.setString(4, newScheduleID);

        sqlUpdate.setInt(5, newPrice);

        sqlUpdate.setInt(6, TicketNo);

        int rslt = sqlUpdate.executeUpdate();
        System.err.println("Result code from Update: " + rslt);
        if (rslt == 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Update app = new Update();
        boolean connOK = app.connect();
        if (connOK) {
            try {
                app.updateTicket();
                app.displayAll(); // from superclass
                app.connection.close();
                System.out.println("\nConnection closed.  Goodbye.");
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.err.println("There was a problem with the DB.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Struggling to workout why the database linkup with access is bringing in errors. cannot seem to update the field in the database.

Comment: Can you provide more detail on error and post the stacktrace

Comment: Basically we are trying to link a database through elcipse. And we are trying to edit a ticket system. So on this ticket system we are triyng to update tickets and send it back to the database through eclipse. Here is an image of the problem http://imgur.com/a/bQRKC